# how remove bintray upload file with -debug.aar filename

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, bintray

I am newbie for android Bintray upload script. I write `build.gradle` such as 
my library `.aar` and `.jar` file generate with custom name. locally I build the project it works fine. but I run Bintray task it upload `.aar` file with append `-debug` word to file name.

I don't know where I am wrong. please help me.

my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.bintray"
    version "1.7.3"
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'

group = 'com.kickdrill'
version = '0.1.1.0.1'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

android {
    publishNonDefault true
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.libraryVariants.all {
                variant - >
                    variant.outputs.each {
                        output - >
                            def alignedOutputFile = variant.outputs[0].outputFile
                            //        def unalignedOutputFile = output.packageApplication.outputFile

                        logger.warn('You got to variant: ' + variant + ' and output:    ' + output)
                            // Customise APK filenames (to include build version)
                        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled) {
                            // normal APK
                            output.outputFile = new File(alignedOutputFile.parent, alignedOutputFile.name.replace("-debug.aar", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".aar"))
                        }
                        // 'unaligned' APK
                    }
            }

        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            android.libraryVariants.all {
                variant - >
                    variant.outputs.each {
                        output - >
                            def alignedOutputFile = variant.outputs[0].outputFile
                            //        def unalignedOutputFile = output.packageApplication.outputFile

                        logger.warn('You got to variant: ' + variant + ' and output: ' + output)
                            // Customise APK filenames (to include build version)
                        if (variant.buildType.zipAlignEnabled) {
                            // normal APK
                            output.outputFile = new File(alignedOutputFile.parent, alignedOutputFile.name.replace("-release.aar", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".aar"))
                        }
                        // 'unaligned' APK
                    }
            }

        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

}



dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
        module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
artifacts {
    archives generateSourcesJar
}
bintray {
    user = project.hasProperty('bintrayUser') ? project.property('bintrayUser') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_USER')
    key = project.hasProperty('bintrayApiKey') ? project.property('bintrayApiKey') : System.getenv('BINTRAY_API_KEY')
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = 'androidkickdrill'
        name = 'easyandroid'
        userOrg = 'androiddevs'
        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        publish = true
        vcsUrl = 'https://github.com/kickdrilldev/KickDrillDevs'
        version {
            name = 'androidkickdrill'
            desc = 'its for an android developer'
            vcsTag = version
            attributes = ['gradle-plugin': 'com.use.less:com.use.less.gradle:gradle-useless-plugin']
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current configuration you have set `publishNonDefault` to `true` which means you want to upload all variants (`debug` and `release`). If you want only `release` to be uploaded remove this line :

```
publishNonDefault true
```

only release variant will be uploaded : `app-1.0.aar` will be uploaded.

If you want both `debug` and `release` variants to be uploaded, you don't need to do anything since the version name will appear in the published variants : `app-<version>-<variant>.aar`. Removing `-<variant>` here would not be relevant since you couldn't differentiate your published variants.

---

If you want to include jar source and javadoc, you can add the following :

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    failOnError false
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

In Bintray, it would look like :

[image]

Comment: hi bertrand,Thanks.

Comment: You are a GOD !